# Problema con clase Scanner en menu numerico y de tipo String con espacios

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en **Java**, donde necesito utilizar la clase `Scanner`para ofrecer a la interfaz opciones del 1 al 6 (en numero) y posteriormente elecciones de una o mas palabras.

El ejemplo es el de un Aeropuerto, donde primero se exhibe un menu de tipo numerico `int` y posteriormente dentro del menu, opciones de tipo String, como el nombre del aeropuerto, pais, ciudad, calle, etc (lo cual, pueden ser 1 o mas palabras separadas por espacios).

He intentado hacerlo como describo el codigo de abajo, pero cuando tengo que elegir la primera opcion, que obligatorialmente tiene que ser un numero del menu, no lo toma, pues **creo** que la clase `Scanner` lo toma como una letra.

Solo paso la primera parte del codigo, donde tengo el problema con useDelimiter:

```
public class GestionAeropuerto {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion, inauguracion, capacidad, tipo;
    String nombre, pais, ciudad, calle;

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("1.- Añadir Aeropuerto");
        System.out.println("2.- Añadir Avion");
        System.out.println("3.- Informacion sobre el Aeropuerto");
        System.out.println("4.- Cantidad de años de apertura del Aeropuerto");
        System.out.println("5.- Ganancias del Aeropuerto");
        System.out.println("6.- Salir del Sistema");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");

        try {

            System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

            opcion = sc.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {

            case 1:

                System.out.println("Nombre del Aeropuerto");
                nombre = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Pais del Aeropuerto");
                pais = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Ciudad del Aeropuerto");
                ciudad = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Calle del Aeropuerto");
                calle = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Año de Inauguracion");
                inauguracion = validarDatos(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, sc);
                System.out.println("Capacidad del Aeropuerto");
                capacidad = validarDatos(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, sc);
                System.out.println("1. - Privado - 2. - Publico ");
                tipo = validarDatos(1, 2, sc);

                break;

            case 2:

                break;

            case 3:

                break;

            case 4:

                break;

            case 5:

                break;

            case 6:

                break;

            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Por favor inserte un numero");
            sc.next();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Para que usas el método `useDelimiter()`? Si lo quitas, deja de dar la excepción..

Comment: @MrDave1999 pero si lo saco, y luego cuando me pide un ciudad de 2 palabras, como hago para que me tome las 2 palabras, y no solo una?

Comment: Con `nextLine()` te toma palabras separadas con espacio. Es decir, si ingreso el nombre de la ciudad: `Miami Beach`, el método toma las dos palabras (`Miami` y `Beach`). Aunque en tu pregunta deberías de dar más detalles del porque necesitas usar `useDelimiter()`.

Comment: genial amigo! voy a probarlo! Es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo, y el usuario utilizo useDelimiter. La verdad estoy probando un poco ese metodo, pero definitivamente no esta ayudando en mucho. Gracias!!!

Comment: Deberías de editar la pregunta y especificar el motivo del porque usas el método `useDelimiter`, de este modo, podría darte una respuesta..

Comment: @MrDave1999 estoy probando utilizar solo nextLine(), sin embargo, no me funciona, ya que el metodo, hace que se vaya a otra linea y luego la clase Scanner me pide todos los datos al mismo tiempo. Edite el codigo para que puedas verlo.

Comment: ¿En el método validarDatos usas el método `nextInt()` ?

Comment: Si amigo, en el metodo validarDatos solo valido si son numeros las entradas del usuario con sc.nextInt();

Comment: @MrDave1999 amigo! solucione el problema. Para poder solventarlo despues del llamado al metodo nextInt, agregamos una linea: sc.nextLine(); Luego podemos utilizar todos los nextLine() sin problema.

Comment: Si encontraste la solución, puedes responder tu mismo pregunta :)

Comment: Hecho @MrDave1999!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solucion!
Despues de cualquier nextInt() se agrega la linea de codigo :

```
opcion = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```

Donde la ultima linea, nos va a permitir utilizar luego todos los nextLine() sin problemas.
No es recomendable utilizar el userDelimiter en el caso mencionado.